# retrieve id of the network with openstack API and shell script

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I need to retrieve the id of the network created with shell script and openstack API. Is there a way to do so?

```
neutron net-create test-net --provider:network_type vlan --provider:physical_network physnet2 --provider:segmentation_id 22  
neutron subnet-create test-net --name test-subnet --allocation-pool start=10.153.9.20,end=10.153.9.34 --gateway 10.153.8.1 10.153.8.0/22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `neutron net-list`[[1]](http://docs.openstack.org/cli-reference/content/neutronclient_commands.html#neutronclient_subcommand_net-list) giving as parameter the `tenant_id` and then pipe the response to grep to selected the network you want by its name

```
neutron --os-tenant-id {tenant_id} net-list | grep {network_name}
```

you will get something like this as response

> | {network_id} | {network_name} | {subnets} |

Comment: I found a way which is to use `neutron subnet-list | grep vpx-eg-subnet | awk '{print $2}'` based on your answer. Thanks!